# Display half value of original from pojo in base adapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am getting value in my base adapter class. I want to display half of it and set it to `TextView`. How to do that in the `Adapter` class ?

```
holder.txtDiscount.setText(pojo.getCashback().substring(2)+"%"+"\nDiscount");
```

`pojo.getCashback()` gets the value. I want to display the half of it. For example, if I get 0.20, `TextView` should display 0.10.

Comment: Can you be please more specific? If there is an error, can you post the logcat stacktrace?

Comment: i have no errors. just want to display half of the number which i am getting from pojo class in my base adapter

Comment: i did but getting error - error - Operator "/" cannot be applied to 'java.lan.String', 'double'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to divide your value by 2. Like:

```
double half = Integer.parseInt(pojo.getCashback().substring(2)) / 2.0;
```

and then show it in your `TextView`:

```
holder.txtDiscount.setText(half + "%" + "\nDiscount");
```

Comment: error - Operator "/" cannot be applied to 'java.lan.String', 'double'

Comment: Is your discount always an integer ?

Comment: If you are 100% sure your String always display a whole number you can do it with `Integer.parseInt(...)`

Answer (score 1):

you can divide by:

```
double totalValue = Double.parseDouble(YourString);
double result = ((double) totalValue ) / 2;
```